# No chrome Binary at the given path - MacOS - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just started to work with selenium web driver with chromedrivers. I am using MacOS and When I try to set the path for the chrome browser as a binary path I always face the same error saying no chrome binary at so and so path given.

```
import os  
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.path.abspath("drivers/chromedriver") , chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

The given path in `chrome_options.binary_location` is correct and that is where I find my chrome browser. I also have included my chromedriver inside the project folder itself

[image]

```
/Applications/Codes/Selenium/seleniumproject/ChromeBinary.py:11: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.path.abspath("drivers/chromedriver") , chrome_options = chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Codes/Selenium/seleniumproject/ChromeBinary.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.path.abspath("drivers/chromedriver") , chrome_options = chrome_options)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This resolved the issue

```
chrome_options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
```

Comment: genius bro, remember no need to escape with '\' key for blank space guys

Answer (score 0):

Not related to question. But you can avoid using giving path to chrome driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())#, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
```

`webdriver_manager` can be installed using `pip install webdriver_manager`

Answer (score -1):

the binary path provided **'/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'** is not a valid path

try placing `r'/Applications/Google/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google/Chrome'` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your path is not valid , you are using both forward slashes and backward slashes